# Java wait() notify() methods last thread waiting forever

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I were playing with Java synchronization mechanism and faced the situation I can not explain.

In the code sample below I have a simple application which is spawning some threads, which are waiting a signal from an object and notify each other once they have been notified:

```java
public class Main {
    public static final Object o = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    synchronized (o) {
                        o.wait();
                        System.out.println("Some work");
                        o.notify();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " notified someone");
            }).start();
        }
        synchronized (o) {
            o.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

And most of the times application's last created thread is hanging:
The response is:

```
Some work
Some work
Some work
Some work
Some work
Thread-3 notified someone
Thread-4 notified someone
Thread-0 notified someone
Thread-2 notified someone
Thread-1 notified someone
```

After applying trial and error technique I found out that if I put a pause `Thread.sleep(100);` between loop and notification in main thread app starts working fine.

After investigation I found out that threads state right after notification sent from main method is:

```
main "Thread-0" prio=5 Id=13 RUNNABLE
main "Thread-1" prio=5 Id=14 WAITING on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8 owned by "Thread-0" Id=13
main "Thread-2" prio=5 Id=15 WAITING on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8 owned by "Thread-0" Id=13
main "Thread-3" prio=5 Id=16 WAITING on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8 owned by "Thread-0" Id=13
main "Thread-4" prio=5 Id=17 WAITING on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8 owned by "Thread-0" Id=13
main "Thread-5" prio=5 Id=18 BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8 owned by "Thread-0" Id=13
```

And right before the last notification is sent the state is:

```
Thread-4 "Thread-4" prio=5 Id=17 RUNNABLE
Thread-4 "Thread-5" prio=5 Id=18 BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8 owned by "Thread-4" Id=17

// Final state

"Thread-5" prio=5 Id=18 WAITING on java.lang.Object@2133c8f8
```

So that is obvious that the last thread has been blocked from the beginning of the app and unable to receive the notification from the penultimate thread, finally reached critical section code and staying on wait line awaiting for the notification.

Probably it's blocked initially because of there's a clash with main method when they both trying to get the o lock.

It would be nice if someone who much better knows this multithreading stuff give some explanations or just some hints of this behavior to me.

Comment: Try putting the `Thread.sleep(1000);` somewhere before `o.notify();`.

Comment: Yes I've already tried that. And it's working fine, but I don't understand why. Because one of the waiting threads receiving the notification from main even without it

Comment: In their current form, the threads notify each other very fast, and there's a chance that the last thread is not running when all the other threads have completed, so the `o.notify();` doesn't notify anyone. Then the last thread `o.wait()`s, and nothing happens (`notify()`s are instantenous, they're not "buffered" for future use if they don't find anyone to wake up). When you `sleep()` prior to `o.notify()`, you give chance to all the threads to reach the waiting phase. Creating new threads is somewhat slow, that's why the threads can take over.

Comment: That’s not how `wait` and `notify` are supposed to be used. You need to define some sort of *condition* you’re waiting for. Then, within the `synchronized` block, check the condition first, to only wait when not fulfilled, and test and wait in a loop. That’s the only way to deal with a) the fact that the condition might be fulfilled already and b) *spurious wakeups*, which are allowed by the specification. Read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#:~:text=The%20recommended%20approach,spurious%20wakeups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're noticing the distinction between a thread waiting to enter a synchonized block ( BLOCKED ) and a thread blocked on a wait() call ( WAITING.)

You have a race condition in your loop.You create your threads and start them. Most of them will make it to the synchronized block. Each of those threads gets to a synchronize block, grabs the lock, and releases it on the wait.

The last thread doesn't have time to run to the synchonized block before your main thread enters the synchronized block. Once your main has acquired the lock on your object, notifies a Thread waiting on the lock. That thread wakes up and acquires the lock, without letting the last thread into the synchronized block.

The first five threads finish and notify, and one thread notifies nobody. Then the last thread has a chance to enter the synchronized block and call wait, but it will never get notified.

That is why the Thread.sleep helps, because your last thread will have time to reach the synchronized block and wait.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I agree with you, I guess it’s even explains why in the most of the cases the if suppose that the speed of creation of the thread is close to the speed of reaching `wait()` from the start of execution

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in calling notify when no other thread is waiting. Semaphores and job queues highlight what you are missing

Semaphore

```
public class Semaphore {
  private int tickets;
  public Semaphore (int tickets) {
    this.tickets = ticket;
  }

  public synchronized void getTicket() {
    if (tickets > 0) {
      tickets--;
    } else {
      while (tickets == 0) {
        wait();
      }
      tickets--;
    }
  }

  public synchronized void releaseTicket() {
    tickets++;
    notify();
  }
}
```

A job queue works similarly, but instead of tickets, it has a queue of `Runnables`. When a thread calls getJob, if there's a job on the queue, it dequeues the job and hands it to the thread. Otherwise, the thread waits for a job.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, it's clearly seen that the last thread is in BLOCKED state instead of WAITING and the notify signal ignored by it. My question is why the last and only the last thread is being blocked, but others are waiting, which I expect. That's what I still can't get

Comment: @ЕвгенийРябов The answer is that when the 2nd to last thread calls `notify`, the last thread hasn't yet `wait`ed on the lock object. Thread.sleep(1000) in between wait and notify would probably fix it, but this is just a kludge; use are using Thread.sleep to mock the time a job takes, but in reality it could more or less than this. Your solution (what you've posted here) isn't thread safe. Using a Semaphore or a MessageQueue (as I've demonstrated) would be the best way to make this thread safe

Comment: [It should be](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#:~:text=The%20recommended%20approach,spurious%20wakeups) `while(tickets == 0) { wait(); } tickets--;`

Comment: @Holger Good advice, albeit a bit nuanced. Defensive coding is never wrong and often right

Comment: In this case, it is strictly required, because it’s possible that thread A increments `tickets` to one and calls `notify()`, which wakes up thread B, but before B proceeds, thread C steps in and finds `ticket` to be one and decrements it without waiting. So, even if *spurious wakeups* were not possible, it would be possible, that `tickets` is zero when returning from `wait()`.

Comment: @Holger yes, true. I have corrected the code

Comment: @Holger the timing would have to be pretty immaculate though. Still, this is more than a nuanced comment, as it could happen and could be a significant bug in a business setting

Comment: Actually, the unfair nature of synchronization gives a new thread trying to enter the `synchronized` block a higher chance of proceeding than a thread waking up from a `wait()` call.

Comment: @Holger re:"unfair nature" I didn't know that, but I believe you. Makes me think that they should have designed Java in a better way right from the beginning to avoid these kinds of common pitfalls.

Comment: It’s not badly designed. It’s just that concurrency is a complex topic, even if the language features make it look like being easy-to-use.

Comment: @Holger "Re: It's just that concurrency is a complex topic" that, my friend, is why the term "Software Engineering" is a joke. When Boeing screwed up the autopilot for the 737 max... or bridges collapse. If we hold Boeing responsible for the lives lost with the 737 max plane crashes, shouldn't we be holding programming language designers to a higher standard when software failures result in deaths or catastrophic financial loses? (See for example Therac II or Expediters)